# How to convert dataframe to matrix without column names

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to convert a dataframe into a numeric-only matrix.  My goal:

> num [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...

***And that's all.***

```
alpha <- beta <- gamma <- delta <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

M1 <- as.matrix(df, ncol = ncol(df))
str(M1)

M2 <- data.matrix(df)
str(M2)
```

> num [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
>    - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>     ..$ : NULL
>     ..$ : chr [1:4] "alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta"

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it without all the attributes.  I need the pure form as input to another method.

Comment: `unname(as.matrix(df))` ?

Comment: `dimnames(M1) <- NULL`.

Answer (score 8):

@thelatemail was absolutely right.

```
unname(as.matrix(df))
```

Does the trick.